# Chart.js + Intel XDK

Tags: android, intel-xdk, chart.js

I'm triyng to add a chart to my Android app using Chart.js

At Intel-XDK emulator this works perfectly, but if I try run it using App Preview or if I build the apk I can't see the chart.

```
function Skills(){
        document.getElementById("MinhasHabilidades").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("inicio").style.display = 'none';

        var ChartData = {
            labels: ["Ler", "Ouvir", "Escrever", "Falar"],
            datasets: [{
                fillColor: "rgba(0,128,255,0.5)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data: [9, 13, 4, 12]
            }]
        };

        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
        window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Radar(ChartData, {responsive: true});
    }
```

When I call the "new Chart(ctx)..." the function stop.

Comment: What happens if you try running in the Debug tab?  That should be similar to running in App Preview, except that you can do debugging stuff like examining variables and set breakpoints.  If you set a breakpoint on the line that calls `new Chart` you can look at `Chart`, `ctx`  and `Chart(ctx).Radar` to see where the problem is.  You may also get some idea on whether Chart.js is being loaded properly.

Comment: Hi my friend, in Debug tab it works... I can see the chart normally, looks like the Debug and the "normal" App Preview are different.

Comment: Yes, they are similar but can be slightly different.  If it works in the Debugger, you might try a Crosswalk build.  I tried your code in App Preview and as a built Android app and it works for me (sorry).  If you want to try posting a complete example that doesn't work for you, I could see if I can reproduce.

Comment: Hi, I already solve it... the problem is that using cordova the js file need to be called as case-sensitive (Chart.js) and I'm using chart.js:

<script src="js/chart.js"></script> TO <script src="js/Chart.js"></script>